# How can I find out in which release my salesforce Organization was created?

Tags: release

Is there any way to find out in which release my Salesforce Organization was created?

Answer (score 3):

Look at one of the standard objects that are created when an org is first generated. For instance, your [Company Information](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_profile.htm&language=en_US) or your [System Administrator profile](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=standard_profiles.htm&language=nl) will be generated when the org is created. These objects will have a created date on them. You should then be able to look back through past releases until you find the release your org was generated based on the date one of those were created.

Comment: -How to find release based on Date.. Is there any way to find out it within salesforce

Comment: Murali, he just told you how to find the date. Then you have to do some work (gasp) to find the release. It won't just be handed to you.

Comment: As a rough guide, February is Spring, June is Summer and October is Winter (of next year). This is not always the case, though.

Comment: @Murali I am not aware of a specific location where they have all the release dates. That would take a bit of research.